# Prove the inequality Using Mean Value theorem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, inequality

Show that : $$x < \log\Bigl(\frac{1}{1-x}\Bigr) < \frac{x}{1 - x}\,;$$
If $$0 < x < 1$$

Solution:

If $$f(x) = \log\Bigl(\frac{1}{1 - x}\Bigr)$$
Then the function is continuous in [0, x] 
And also differentiable in (0, x) 
So We can apply Lagrange's MVT on f(x).

Fine!

So $$f'(x) =\frac{1}{1 - x}$$
As per LMVT : $$f(x) - f(0) = xf'(θx) ;$$
Where : $$0 < θ < 1$$

=> $$xf'(θx) = - \log(1 - x) $$

=> $$\frac{x} {1 - θx} = - \log(1 - x)$$

=>  $$\frac{x} {1 - θx} = - \log(1 - x)......... (1)$$

So, $$0 < θx < x$$

Or  $$0 > - θx >  - x $$

Or  $$1 >  1 - θx  >  1 - x $$

Or  $$1 < \frac{1} {1 - θx} < \frac{1} {1 - x} $$

Or  $$x <  \frac{x} {1 - θx} <\frac{x}{1 - x} $$

Or  $$x <  - \log(1 - x) < \frac{x} {1 - x}... \text{ from } (1)$$

Or

$$x < \log\Bigl(\frac{1}{1 - x}\Bigr) <\frac{x}{1 - x}$$

Comment: But what have you tried? It would be nice if you could show your attempts and where you got stuck.

Comment: Ok I am editing it. And showing till where I went.

Comment: @user296113 Yes, precisely what I was hinting at. Funny how OP included the [tag:proof-verification] tag when there is no proof to be seen.

Comment: $x<x/(1-x)$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: The inequalities should be reversed.

Comment: Please improve formatting by using Mathjax. Your question is barely readable in its current state.

Comment: I have made all the necessary changes. Now someone please point out where am I wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still find your question to be quite unreadable.  It might be helpful to read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), paying special attention to the `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` environment.  Also note that `$\implies$` is rendered as $\implies$.

Comment: I think its definitely readable now. And I request all those who showed an interest in this post, to help me out. Because I know you all might have been excellent in this field of Mathematics, but trust me I am not excellent. So I am asking for a little help. So if you can help me out then please otherwise please don't give excuses of format.

Comment: I would also like to thank @Bernard for this supportive hint.

Comment: @KalpadiptyaRoy: You have an initial sign error in the computation of $f'(x)$: it is equal to $\;\dfrac1{1-x}$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot. I am really grateful to you.

Comment: I am correcting my mistake in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The inequalities should be reversed.

Start from the well-known inequality
$$\log u\le u-1\quad\text{for all }u>0\qquad(< \text{ if } u\ne1),$$
and make the relevant substitutions.

*Some details*:

First set $\;u=\dfrac1{1-x}$ (which is positive since $0<x<1$). You obtain instantly
$$\log\frac1{1-x} <\frac1{1-x}-1=\frac x{1-x}.$$

Now set $u=1-x$: you get
$$\log(1-x)<(1-x)-1=-x\iff \log\frac1{1-x}>-(-x)=x.$$